# How to retrieve shared_dataextension dataextension using soap api

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, soap

how to retrieve shared_dataextension using soap api? I tried so many ways but I am not getting perfect result. I am using below Code for retrieve data extensions. Except for `shared_Dataextension`, I am getting all dataextensions in soap api response.

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <Header>
 <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
 <UsernameToken>
  <Username>Tst@gmail.com</Username> 
  <Password>Test11222</Password> 
  </UsernameToken>
  </Security>
  </Header>
 <Body>
 <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
 <RetrieveRequest>
    <ObjectType>DataExtension</ObjectType>
    <Properties>Name</Properties>
    <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
   </RetrieveRequest>
 </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </Body>
  </Envelope>
```

Comment: Are you accessing it via the parent business unit?

Comment: @ Data_Kid 
Yes  I given access to parent Business unit.

Comment: @Data_Kid 
What are all the options i need to Enable In order to get shared dataextension data from parent business unit.

Comment: Hi @ Data_Kid 
This is Very urgent requirement Please Help me for  this problem.

Comment: @Data_Kid 
 I found answer  thanks for your response.